# Stored Procedure for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have written this stored procedure and it executes but it doesn't update the customer.  The question is: Create a procedure named prc_cus_balance_update that will take the invoice number as a parameter and update the customer balance.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE PRC_CUS_BALANCE_UPDATE3 

    @INV_NUMBER INT 

AS

BEGIN

    DECLARE @CUS_CODE INT

    SELECT @CUS_CODE=CUS_CODE
    FROM INVOICE
    WHERE @INV_NUMBER=INV_NUMBER

    UPDATE CUSTOMER
    SET CUS_BALANCE=CUS_BALANCE + 
        (SELECT INV_TOTAL FROM INVOICE WHERE @INV_NUMBER=INV_NUMBER)
    WHERE @CUS_CODE=CUS_CODE

END
GO
```

Comment: A few suggestions:  Do you perform a commit somewhere?  Does the select from invoice to get the customer code return more than one row?  Is cus_balance null (null + 5) is null.

Comment: I never even thought about it returning more than one row. Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE CUSTOMER    
SET CUS_BALANCE=ISNULL(CUS_BALANCE,0) + ISNULL((SELECT SUM(INV_TOTAL) FROM INVOICE WHERE @INV_NUMBER=INV_NUMBER),0)    
WHERE @CUS_CODE=CUS_CODE

Comment: @user2257844 Your welcome.  The more than one row sounded most likely.  In oracle that throws an exception I wasn't sure about SQL server.  I'm curious what SQL Server does.

Answer (score 0):

While developing, I'd put in some "extras" to figure out what is going on.

Pseudo code below.

You want to make sure you found a matching row.
And you want to make sure at least one row was actually updated.

I'm NOT saying the code below is "production ready".  But will show the concepts.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PRC_CUS_BALANCE_UPDATE3 

    @INV_NUMBER INT 

AS

BEGIN

    DECLARE @CUS_CODE INT
    DECLARE @MYROWCOUNT INT

    SELECT @CUS_CODE=CUS_CODE
    FROM INVOICE
    WHERE @INV_NUMBER=INV_NUMBER

    if(Not(@CUS_CODE IS NULL))
        BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT OFF

        UPDATE CUSTOMER
        SET CUS_BALANCE=CUS_BALANCE + 
            (SELECT INV_TOTAL FROM INVOICE WHERE @INV_NUMBER=INV_NUMBER)
        WHERE @CUS_CODE=CUS_CODE


        select @MYROWCOUNT = @@ROWCOUNT

        if(@MYROWCOUNT <=0)
            BEGIN
                print 'No row updated.    :<'
            END


        SET NOCOUNT OFF


        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            print "@CUS_CODE match not found."
        END

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting some better bulletproofing in.  Multiple rows, null values, and the like, can all cause problems with how you currently have it.  Here's a stab at it, without me knowing the specifics of your data model (it may not be appropriate to sum together the totals from invoices, I'm just saying you could have multiple rows and need to deal with that).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PRC_CUS_BALANCE_UPDATE3 
    @INV_NUMBER INT 
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @CUS_CODE INT

    SELECT 
        TOP 1 @CUS_CODE = CUS_CODE
    FROM 
        INVOICE
    WHERE 
        INV_NUMBER=@INV_NUMBER

    IF @CUS_CODE IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        UPDATE 
            CUSTOMER
        SET 
            CUS_BALANCE = ISNULL(CUS_BALANCE, 0.0) + 
            ISNULL(
                (SELECT 
                    SUM(INV_TOTAL) 
                FROM 
                    INVOICE 
                WHERE 
                    @INV_NUMBER = INV_NUMBER), 
            0.0)
        WHERE 
            CUS_CODE = @CUS_CODE    
    END
END
GO
```